# Line break in between two messages in one prompt of particular field in Microsoft FormFlow

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there any way to put line break in between two messages in one prompt of particular field in Microsoft FormFlow for creating bot?

This is my code statement for field "Organisation".
I want to put line break between two Messages in one prompt.

```
[Prompt("Nice to meet you. Can I know name of your Organization? {||}"
String organisation;

1.Nice to meet you.
2.Can I know name of your Organisation?
```

I want to put new line between this two messages. How would I do that?

Comment: Do you mean **(1)** you want add a newline between the prompt and the list of options or **(2)** you want to add a newline between each option in the list?

Comment: I want to add new line between statement (1) and statement (2) that is in my Prompt.-@GrishaLevit

Answer (score 1):

Just update your prompt to include the new line code. I tested the following and worked for me:

```
[Prompt("Nice to meet you. \n\n Can I know name of your Organization? {||}")]
```

[image]